# Factorization of polynomials with coefficients in arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

I was pondering the existence of cubic polynomials of the form

$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d,$$

where the constants $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are all **non-zero integer consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression**, such that the polynomial can be factorized as a product of three linear factors of the form $(ex+f)(gx+h)(ix+j)$, where $e,f,g,h,i$ and $j$ are integers.

Can anyone think of an example of such a polynomial? Is there a general rule to describe them?

Comment: Do we care about the order of the consecutive terms (in other words, could we have $a=u_{n+1}$ and $b=u_{n}$ or $b=u_{n-1}$ for some arithmetic sequence ?

Comment: What have you tried? What ideas do you have about this?

Comment: @BastienTourand Yes, specifically I'm interested in seeing if there are ordered sequences $a = u_{n-1}, b = u_{n}, c = u_{n+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot a bunch of these polynomials you'll notice that they all only have one real root, so they don't admit such a factorization even over the reals. This turns out to be true! Here's a somewhat nasty proof but it works. Write the polynomial as

$$p(x) = (a - 3d) x^3 + (a - d) x^2 + (a + d) x + (a + 3d)$$

(an arithmetic progression but where $a$ is the average instead of the initial term and the common difference is $2d$). [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discriminant+of+%28a+-+3d%29+x%5E3+%2B+%28a+-+d%29+x%5E2+%2B+%28a+%2B+d%29+x+%2B+%28a+%2B+3d%29) very helpfully tells us that the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) of this polynomial is

$$-16 (a^4 - 22 a^2 d^2 + 125 d^4) = -16 ((a^2 - 11d^2)^2 + 4d^4)$$

and in particular it is always negative, which means $p(x)$ has exactly one real root.

(Maybe [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) or [Budan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budan%27s_theorem) could be used to give a different proof?)